# ¡Felicitemos a Charlie y Diego por llegar a 30 000 puntos y a guifa a 20 000!

Tags: discusión, usuarios

Observo que [Charlie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12637/charlie) acaba de llegar a los 30 000 puntos de reputación. ¡Enhorabuena!

[Diego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/5481/diego) está a punto de llegar (al fin y al cabo, fue el usuario con mayor reputación durante un par de años) y [guifa](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/4182/guifa) llegó a los 20 000 hace pocas semanas.

A ver si se pican por el liderato y llegan a los 40 000 en pocos meses :)

Demos las gracias a todos ellos por contribuir tan activa y persistentemente a que el sitio sea útil y bueno.

Comment: Enhorabuena @Charlie!

Comment: En mi caso 1 upvote = 1 agradecimiento a todos por el reconocimiento :-)

Comment: Edité el título para mencionar también a los campeones Diego y guifa, igualmente merecedores de reconocimiento :)

Comment: ¡Enhorabuena a todos!  Bien hecho y bien merecido.