# Retrospectiva de 2017 en Spanish.se // Spanish.se 2017 Retrospective

Tags: discusión, site-evaluation

En el desarrollo de software (sé que muchos de los aquí presentes hemos acabado en este stack de forma tangencial debido a [stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/) y a [stack**overflow** en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), así que esto no os sonará muy raro) un **sprint** en una unidad de tiempo (unas dos semanas) durante el cual el equipo de trabajo trata de sacar adelante un cierto trabajo.

Mi equipo siempre termina los *sprints* haciendo (entre otras cosas) una retrospectiva del *sprint*. La mecánica de esta reunión a veces varía un poco (para no aburrirnos y para probar cosas nuevas), pero normalmente incluyen:

- Cosas que hemos hecho bien y de las que estamos orgullosos. Pueden ser cosas puntuales o metodologías que queramos mantener.
- Cosas que han salido mal y de las que tenemos que investigar el porqué y evitar en lo posible que se repintan.
- Ideas nuevas. Esto en parte viene motivado y relacionado con las dos anteriores.
- Acción de gracias (una traducción libre de *appreciations*): Agradecemos a miembros del equipo ayuda que nos han prestado y otras cosas que han hecho para el bien del equipo.

La motivación de este post es tener una discusión sobre lo que ha sido 2017 en Spanish.se. Sé que "(todo) 2017" es un periodo de tiempo muy largo, pero como acabamos de empezar 2018, el calendario invita a hacer una retrospectiva de 2017 y plantear algunas cosas para 2018.

Los puntos que he mencionado anteriormente deberían ser una ayuda, más que una restricción. Si a alguien le ayudan a pensar o redactar un post, mejor. En caso contrario que se sienta libre de participar con el formato que considere oportuno o que mejor le ayude a expresar sus ideas.

La idea de esta retrospectiva es fomentar un poco de reflexión y discusión, y con ello crear (más) post de meta para discutir ideas y otras cosas que veamos aquí.

Así que, en 2017 en Spanish.se

- ¿Qué hemos hecho bien (y queremos seguir manteniendo así)?
- ¿Qué hemos hecho o estamos haciendo mal y nos debemos replantear?
- ¿Qué ideas nuevas tenemos para probar (estas son en sí nuevos post meta)
- ¿Qué actitudes/esfuerzos queremos destacar y elogiar?

Comment: Y por supuesto, Feliz 2018 a todos!

Comment: Muy buena iniciativa Diego, ¡deberíamos hacer esto a partir de ahora todos los años!

Answer (score 5):

### GOOD

- Creo que la **participación en meta** ha mejorado un poco. Recuerdo temporadas en las que esto estaba desierto, y podías publicar en meta y pasaba una buena temporada antes de que alguien se diese cuenta de que había un post nuevo. Ahora parece que meta está bastante activo (para los estándares de nuestros stack en perpetua beta). Algunas de estas propuestas han **experimentado bastante con los límites del sitio**, lo cual es una cosa buena salga adelante la propuesta o no (como el incluir los tags de idiomas, o el permitir por un día preguntas off-topic en el sitio)
- Veo **nuevos usuarios que participan más**, o que han llegado para quedarse (como [Mauricio Martínez](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/17686/mauricio-martinez)).
- Hemos hecho bastantes intentos por **ayudar a los recién llegados** (el más reciente es [Let's train new participants to ask well-constructed questions](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2763/5481), pero tenemos también otros ejemplos como [How many days to wait before fixing someone else's question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2693/5481), [Site etiquette proposal: do not downvote answers by newcomers](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2747/5481) y algunos [comentarios "enlatados" para ayudar en las tareas de revisión](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2622/5481)).
- Se participa más en las colas de revisión.

### BAD

- Nuestras preguntas por día han bajado un poco. No es que yo sea un fan de las estadísticas y siempre he defendido que no pasa nada por no pasar de beta. Mirando [las estadísticas del Área 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language), las preguntas por día es algo que siempre ha sido tarea pendiente (o habríamos pasado de beta, claro), pero ahora mismo están especialmente bajas, y cuando hay menos preguntas la gente entra con menos frecuencia, y por tanto participa menos en las colas de revisión, meta, etc. (Relacionado: [Preguntad, preguntad, malditos](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2713/5481)).
- Relacionado con la anterior, creo que en ocasiones hemos sacrificado un poco la calidad de nuestras preguntas en pro de no tener un número de preguntas por día irrisorio. Supongo que esto puede ser apreciación mía, y posiblemente daría para su propio post-discusión en meta, pero creo que no deberíamos perder la perspectiva del tipo de preguntas que queremos tener.
- Además, nuestras preguntas suelen tener pocas respuestas por pregunta. A veces es difícil aportar una explicación adicional cuando ya hay una respuesta a la pregunta, pero explicar las cosas con ejemplos distintos o de otra manera puede enriquecer la explicación. Deberíamos animarnos más a encontrar una manera de publicar más respuestas por pregunta (cosa que creo que ya hemos discutido en meta también).
- Otras cosa que puede ser apreciación mía y posiblemente también esté relacionada con los puntos anteriores: ¿Estamos votando menos? ¿Es porque ha bajada un poco la participación recientemente debido a la escasez de preguntas? ¿Es porque ha bajado la calidad? O estoy yo equivocado, y se vota más o menos igual que antes (que suele ser poco. Relacionado: [¿Se vota poco en este Stack?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2446/5481))

### IDEAS

- Seguir con los intentos de educar a los nuevos usuarios.
- Hacer nuevos intentos por publicar más preguntas. Recordatorio: No va contra las normas del sitio responder vuestras propias preguntas, así que alguna de esas veces que os resolvéis una duda a vosotros mismos, todavía puede quedar un post interesante para el sitio.
- Otra idea [futuro post meta que los moderadores todavía estamos evaluando y preparando. "*Coming soon*"]: Meta-post con las mejores preguntas/respuestas de cada trimestre. Esto es algo que se hace en otros stacks, como el de [Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) y pensamos que podría ser una forma interesante de hacer varias cosas de una vez: Dar mayor visibilidad a ciertas preguntas, premiar buenos posts, aumentar los votos (que viene bien que la gente tenga rep suficiente para ciertas tareas de moderación y mejora del sitio, como participar en las colas de revisión...).

### APPRECIATIONS

Entiendo que el problema de agradecer o alabar cuando en la comunidad participa tanta gente es que corres el riesgo de olvidarte de algo o de alguien, así que por favor, que nadie se ofenda ni considere esta lista como "definitiva" o "exclusiva".

- Empiezo, como no podría ser de otra manera, con mi compañero moderador [fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1674/fedorqui), al que le debemos muchas de las cosas que van bien en este sitio. El trabajo de moderador a veces no se nota, pero ha tenido contribuciones muy destacadas destinadas a mejorar nuestro stack.
- [Carlos Alejo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12637/charlie), por sus estelares contribuciones, el [translation golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-golf) y otros logros (entre ellos, haber conseguido que Arturo Pérez-Reverte [nos respondiera a una duda](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17172/12637)). Fedorqui destacó hace poco algunas de sus contribuciones en [¡Felicitemos a Charlie y Diego por llegar a 30 000 puntos y a guifa a 20 000!](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2734/5481)
- A [aparente001](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9385/aparente001), por sus múltiples intentos en meta de promover una (mejor) cultura de "[be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)", especialmente a través de todos esos post sobre cómo mejorar el trato hacia los recién llegados.
- A [walen](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/13628/walen), [mdewey](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/12155/mdewey) y [DGaleano](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11102/dgaleano), por su participación constante en las colas de revisión.
- [Y alguno más del que me olvido. Es ya un poco tarde y acumulo el cansancio de las fiestas navideñas... Mañana cuando me acuerde de más gente los iré poniendo aquí y agradeciendo sus contribuciones.]

Comment: One thing which I have noticed this year is an increase in the participation of people who clearly are linguistics professionals which has increased the depth of the responses. Perhaps this is just my perception though.

Answer (score 2):

Agregando algo a la aportación de Diego:

GOOD

- La Tertulia, creo que tomó vida en 2017.
- El juego de Golf, creo que también fue un fenómeno de 2017.  ¡La diversión es muy importante!  (como dijo Dr. Seuss, "Fun is good.")
- En Spanish Language Meta, poco a poco, vamos poniéndonos de acuerdo sobre la mecánica y la documentación, por ejemplo, ¿Qué es una buena pregunta?  ¿Qué se debe hacer con preguntas no tan bien planteadas?
- Este stack sigue con el trato cordial que no siempre se encuentra en SE.  Aunque no es un cambio, es un logro, sin embargo.

Perdón, no había leído la sección de agradecimientos, que incluye, creo, todo lo que apunté aquí....  Pero ni modo, voy a dejar mi respuesta de todos modos.

AGRADECIMENTO PERSONAL

Para los expatriados de Ameríca Latina, que no se encuentran en su país nativo (o adoptado), por diversos factores, este sitio es un tesoro.  Es un lugar donde puede uno sentirse conectado con sus cultura a pesar de la distancia de la patria.

Comment: Sobre la mecánica de documentación pienso es una cuestión de tiempo y de que el sitio tome más madurez.

Answer (score 1):

### GOOD

- La incorporación de Diego como moderador ha sido de gran ayuda para poder realizar las tareas de moderación de forma colegiada. Además, ha demostrado ser una persona con gran criterio, buenas formas e ideas interesantes.
- La aparición de [walen](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/13628/walen), [pablodf76](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/14627/pablodf76), [Gustavson](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/14676/gustavson), [blonfu](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/14069/blonfu), [aparente001](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/9385/aparente001), que han dinamizado el sitio con sus preguntas, respuestas y.
- La perseverancia de [Charlie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12637/charlie) a la hora de exponer preguntas cada vez más potentes, ensanchando los límites del sitio constantemente.
- La recuperación de la sala de chat [La Tertulia](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061) como lugar de encuentro e incubadora de ideas, con frecuentes cameos de distintos usuarios.
- El buen ambiente, tacto y positividad en los comentarios, haciendo del sitio un lugar amable (y facilitando la tarea de los moderadores :P)
- El uso de Meta ha aumentado, en general para buscar una mejor definición del sitio.

### BAD

- La desaparición de usuarios fantásticos como [Yay](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/11511/yay).
- Tras el subidón de preguntas por el concurso [Preguntad, preguntad, malditos](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2713/1674), el invierno ha llegado en forma de una caída importante de preguntas, más acentuada que en otros años (véase el [análisis de walen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42104018#42104018)).
- La walen-Charlie-guifa-Diego-Gustavson-pablodf76-dependencia a la hora de contestar. Un tanto por ciento demasiado grande de respuestas viene de ellos.
- La walen-Charlie-Diego-fedorqui-dependencia a la hora de preguntar. Un tanto por ciento demasiado grande de preguntas viene de ellos. ¡Cuando no están se nota demasiado!
- Las tareas de moderación como comunidad cojean un poco: las colas de revisión no tienen demasiada concurrencia, la gente tiende a editar poco (relacionado: [Escribamos títulos de preguntas más concretos y textos con menos ruido](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2485/1674)), no se añaden etiquetas con demasiada frecuencia.
- [Stack Exchange despidió a un 20% de su plantilla](https://techcrunch.com/2017/11/02/stack-overflow-lays-off-staff/) y eso hace pensar que será aún más complicado ver nuevas funcionalidades. Además, preveo que sitios pequeños y no monetarizables como el nuestro bajarán aún más en la lista de prioridades.

### IDEAS

- Que los usuarios más activos se turnen para coger vacaciones en momentos distintos y así siempre tengamos a unos cuantos presentes.
- Recordémonos siempre que por encima de todo está el modelo [Be nice](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) y actuemos en consecuencia: podemos estar de acuerdo o no, pero expresémoslo siempre con mano izquierda y [presumamos buena fe](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Presume_buena_fe) en lo que hacen los demás.

### APPRECIATIONS

- Gracias a Diego por querer formar parte del grupo de moderadores y estar siempre al quite. Su raciocinio y sentido común siempre van de la mano de una forma de proceder próxima y agradable. ¡Es un placer!