# Retrospectiva de 2018 en Spanish.se // Spanish.se 2018 Retrospective

Tags: discusión

Sirva este post para desearos a todos los usuarios feliz entrada y salida del año.

Ahora que estamos a punto de empezar 2019, parece un buen momento para hacer una retrospectiva de lo que ha sido 2018 en nuestro stack, tal y como [hicimos el año pasado](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2765/5481).

La idea es muy simple, oír vuestros pensamientos y opiniones de cualquier tipo sobre el stack. No es necesario seguir ningún formato determinado ni opinar sobre cosas concretas. La idea es poder dar voz a todos los usuarios para que expreséis lo que queráis hacer notar y luego veremos cómo evoluciona la discusión (a través de comentarios o tal vez con otros posts en Meta para cosas particulares) o qué cosas queremos examinar más detenidamente.

Cualquier cosas que queráis hacer notar o decir sobre el stack es bienvenida. No es necesario un "esto está mal y propongo XYZ para arreglarlo". Puede bastar con "A mi me parece que ...".

Y por último daros las **gracias a todos los que formáis parte de este stack y contribuís vuestro tiempo y esfuerzo en él**.

Answer (score 5):

Estas son nuestras estadísticas en [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language) a día de hoy

[image]

Las únicas que no están catalogadas como excelentes son las preguntas por día (2.9 preguntas/día) y las respuestas por pregunta (2.2 respuestas por pregunta).

Ya decía [fedorqui el año pasado](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2777/5481) que en este sitio tenemos una gran dependencia de ciertos usuarios, no solo para responder preguntas sino también para lanzar preguntas nuevas.

No soy partidario de incrementar de forma artificial el número de preguntas por día (y creo que ya hemos asumido todos que este stack va a estar en "beta" de forma permanente) porque eso lleva a tener preguntas de menor calidad, pero sí me preocupa un poco que la falta de preguntas puede ser la principal causa de la falta de actividad.

Entiendo que este stack es para algunos un recurso de aprendizaje y para otros tiene a ser más un hobby. Me preocupa que la falta de algo que hacer (responder) desmotive a algunos usuarios para los que esto es un hobby, ya que creo que son algunos de los mayores contribuidores en preguntas y respuestas, lo que a su vez agrava el problema de la falta de actividad.

Por otro lado, veo que las colas de revisión funcionan bastante bien y que ya sea mediante estas revisiones o directamente, se está ayudando a los usuarios nuevos a alcanzar el nivel de calidad que deseamos en preguntas y respuestas.